# Split view with Project and Problems Tool Window

Tags: intellij-idea

I am about to switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea and I would like to configure IntelliJ to display the same Information as my Eclipse setup. Here is the Tool Window layout I want to achieve:

```
+----------+-----------------------+
|          |                       |
| Project  |     Source editor     |
|          |                       |
|          |                       |
|          |                       |
|          |                       |
+----------+                       |
|          |                       |
| Problems |                       |
|          |                       |
+----------+-----------------------+
```

It is not supposed to hide when it is focused/unfocused. It simply should sit there for me to look at it.

I read [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/viewing-modes.html) guide which tells me that the Project and Problems Tool Window have to be in different tab groups to get this working:

> To be able to see two windows simultaneously, the corresponding windows should belong to different groups, that is, one of the windows should have the split mode off and the other one on.

I understand that and I am able to get the above layout with the Project and Structure Tool Windows. However, since the Project and Problems Tool Windows happen to be in the same tab group, I can't figure out how to get the requests layout. I guess, I have to move the Problems Tool Window to a separate tab group, but I did not find a way to do so.

Thus, my question is, how can I get the above Tool Window layout, which probably comes down to the question: How can I move the Problems Tool Window to another (a new) tab group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standalone Problems tool window available. It's activated after you [enable the automatic compilation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/problems-tool-window.html).

Once activated, enable the split mode for the Problems tool window and move it to the left. Also make sure [side-by-side layout is not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45aRv.png).

Example:

[image: problems]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works fine. But, is there actually no way to move a Tool Window between tag groups?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "tag groups", but you can't represent different project views as the separate and standalone tool windows displayed at the same time.

Comment: Okay, I guess this answers my question. Thanks.